# Django-import-export: Importing ForeignKey fields succeeds only for 1st Value

Tags: django-import-export

When trying to import data via excel, the code only reads first entry from data-base.

```
#resource.py
from .models import(
    Country, GeoMaster
)
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget


class CountryResource(resources.ModelResource):

    geo_master_id= fields.Field(
        column_name= 'geo_master_id',
        attribute='geo_master_id',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(GeoMaster, 'id')
    )
class Meta:
        model = Country
        import_id_fields = ['country_name']
        fields = ( 'id', 'country_name', 'geo_master_id')
```

My model `GeoMaster` contains multiple entries with id's ranging from 1-10

my successful import dataset (geo_master_id=1 is first entry in databse):

```
id|country_name|geo_master_id
--|--------------|--------------|
  |India         |1.0           |
```

un-successful import dataset (geo_master_id=2 is NOT first entry in databse):

```
id|country_name|geo_master_id
--|--------------|--------------|
  |India         |2.0           |
```

Error: GeoMaster matching query does not exist.
Is there somethinf wrong with my #resources.py?

UPDATE:
I added custom widget:

````
class GeoMasterForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):
    def get_queryset(self, value, row):
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            id=row["geo_master_id"],
        )

#to be used in subsequent field

    geo_master_id= fields.Field(
        column_name= 'geo_master_id',
        attribute='geo_master_id',
        widget=GeoMasterForeignKeyWidget(GeoMaster, 'id')
    )```
Still it returns Error: GeoMaster matching query does not exist.
````

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
class GeoMasterForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):
    def get_queryset(self, value, row):
        #print(int(value), row)
        qs= GeoMaster.objects.filter(
            id=int(value),
        )
        print("returning:", qs)
        return qs
```